Active screen edges cannot be disabled on Ubuntu 24.04
I've just installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my desktop (was running Ubunto 22.04 beforehand) and I'd like to disable the Active Screen Edges option (the one that resizes the windows by dragging them against the screen edges). Presumably, this can be done through a designated button in the
Settings -> Multitasking
menu. However, this button does not seem to have any effect: the screen edges remain active regardless of the state of this button.
Any ideas?

There is an issue at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/2066169 which seems to be what you are experiencing.

I had the same problem with my quad screen view.  For me the fix was to first disable Enhanced Tiling under Settings -> Ubuntu Desktop. After that I could successfully disable Active Screen Edges.
If you have no use for Enhanced Tiling, try this first.

Found a fix/workaround in this thread.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/2066169
danste1897 (danste1897) wrote on 2024-07-16 (last edit on 2024-07-16):          #7
Replacing /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com/ (apt info gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-tiling-assistant says 46.1) with the version from github (https://github.com/Leleat/Tiling-Assistant/releases/tag/v47) allows disabling active screen edges from Settings->Multitasking.
Version 47 of tiling assistant on github seems to work as expected in other regards as well.
